# Unable to start SNMP in RHEL5 64-bit

Tags: centos, snmp, rhel5, 64-bit, selinux

I have installed net-snmp, net-snmp-utils and net-snmp-devel in my 64-bit Centos5 using yum.

The following are the packages I've installed:

```
net-snmp-devel-5.3.2.2-14.el5_7.1
net-snmp-utils-5.3.2.2-14.el5_7.1
net-snmp-devel-5.3.2.2-14.el5_7.1
net-snmp-libs-5.3.2.2-14.el5_7.1
net-snmp-libs-5.3.2.2-14.el5_7.1
net-snmp-5.3.2.2-14.el5_7.1
net-snmp-perl-5.3.2.2-14.el5_7.1
```

Starting snmp,

```
[root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/snmpd start
Starting snmpd: /usr/sbin/snmpd: error while loading shared libraries: 
librpmdb4.4.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
                                                           [FAILED]
```

But when I disable SELinux,

```
[root@localhost ~]# setenforce 0
[root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/snmpd start
Starting snmpd:                                            [  OK  ]
```

When I enable SELinux back, it can no longer start successfully.

```
[root@localhost ~]# setenforce 1
[root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/snmpd restart
Stopping snmpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting snmpd: /usr/sbin/snmpd: error while loading shared libraries: 
librpmdb-.4.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
                                                           [FAILED]
```

What should I do? I need my SELinux to be enabled of course. Any configurations that can fix this one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be the default security contexts is not set properly.

So, you can recursively restore the default security contexts  by issuing the command as follow.

First change to the root dir.

```
#cd /
#restorecon -Rv .
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to check the security context.

```
$ ls -alZ
```

You can use the following command to change it:

```
$ chcon
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for my snmp service to work, I execute the command `restorecon` on the libraries involved on running the snmp.

```
restorecon -vv /lib64/libres* 
restorecon -vv /lib64/libnsl* 
restorecon -vv /lib64/libdl*  
restorecon -vv /lib64/libm* 
restorecon -vv /lib64/libcrypt* 
restorecon -vv /lib64/libutil*  
restorecon -vv /lib64/libpthread* 
restorecon -vv /lib64/libc* 
restorecon -vv /lib64/librpmdb* 
restorecon -vv /usr/lib64/librpmdb-4.4.so  
restorecon -vv /lib64/libselinux*  
restorecon -vv /lib64/libnss3*  
restorecon -vv /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
restorecon -vv /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so  
restorecon -vv /usr/lib64/libplds4.so  
restorecon -vv /usr/lib64/libplc4.so 
restorecon -vv /usr/lib64/libnspr4.so   
restorecon -vv /lib64/librt.so.1  
restorecon -vv /lib64/librt*  
restorecon -vv /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1 
restorecon -vv /usr/lib64/libbz2* 
restorecon -vv /lib64/libgcc_s*  
restorecon -vv /usr/lib64/libsysfs*  
restorecon -vv /usr/lib64/libsqlite3* 
restorecon -vv /usr/lib64/libelf*  
restorecon -vv /lib64/libsepol*  
restorecon -vv /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  
restorecon -vv /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64* 
restorecon -vv /lib64/ld-2.5.so
```

`restorecon` reset the security contexts of the above libraries from `system_u:object_r:file_t:s0` to `system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0`